# Magento2: How export custom column in customer grid

Tags: magento2, customer-grid, magento2.4.3.p1

i create a column custom in customer grid but no export my data in excel.
i create the column whit ui_component

/app/code/Vendor/CustomModule/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml

```
<columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns" >
    <column name="origen" class="Vendor\CustomModule\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Origen" sortOrder="90">
        <settings>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Origen</label>
            <sortable>false</sortable>
            <filter>false</filter>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="data" class="Vendor\CustomModule\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Data" sortOrder="90">
        <settings>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Data</label>
            <sortable>false</sortable>
            <filter>false</filter>
        </settings>
    </column>
</columns>
```

how export my columns?. please help me!

Comment: which problem are you facing exactly? are you getting an error?

Comment: No error, i have  a grid in admin but no export of data in csv

Comment: So the CSV has no rows? Or is completely empty? Did you check the server- and Magento-error-logs ? For me I got it working after applying this patch: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/36663